# Как сделать кроссбраузерный overflow: overlay?

Tags: html, css, overflow

Как сделать так, чтобы скроллбар блока появлялся над ним самим без изменения размера содержимого (поверх padding'а). Нужно responsive-решение. По сути надо получить то же самое, что в хроме делает `overflow: overlay`.

Пример:

[image: скринвидео желаемого результата]

Заготовка: http://jsfiddle.net/3gf520ht/

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
main { width: 80%; height: 80%; margin: 10vh auto; border: 1px solid; }
article { text-align: justify; }

main {
  padding: 0 2em;
  overflow: overlay;
}

article {
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pellentesque convallis vestibulum. Proin sed porta urna, eu fermentum velit. Nulla quis accumsan augue, mollis eleifend felis. Aenean venenatis faucibus erat, non ornare ex efficitur ut. Ut ligula urna, auctor non velit quis, ultricies aliquet diam. Nulla quis scelerisque nisl, rutrum consectetur diam. Etiam bibendum tellus orci, iaculis varius risus congue vitae. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum sed velit sit amet quam ultrices facilisis. Mauris malesuada vehicula purus, in blandit lectus pellentesque in. Duis luctus, risus et molestie venenatis, libero ligula volutpat augue, vitae bibendum arcu leo vel ligula. Etiam aliquet semper velit ut fringilla.</article>
</main>
```

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском](//stackoverflow.com/q/53856627/4928642).

Comment: `main { overflow-y: auto; }` Либо я чего то не понимаю, либо это очень простое решение?

Comment: Не понимаешь. Сравни с гифкой. Когда появляется скролл, правая граница текста сдвигается. А надо, чтобы оставалась на месте.

Comment: Слева overlay, а справа auto: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbkDf.gif А вот в виде фиддла: http://jsfiddle.net/3gf520ht/2/

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял. Ну чего то елегантного на CSS я не знаю. Можно в лоб на JS написать

Comment: Ну там тоже не так в лоб, как кажется, потому что отследить изменение размера элемента - само по себе жирная задача с решениями разной сомнительности (у ResizeObserver поддержка [сильно так себе](https://caniuse.com/#feat=resizeobserver) - только Хром 64+), но в целом возможно. Хотелось именно на css чего-то замутить. Даже есть один вариант (на самом деле, это баг Хрома и IE), который работает в Хроме и почти работает в IE... Но хром и так шикарно со своим overlay всё делает.

Answer (score 1):

Ну на JS я сделал, если что можно заюзать http://jsfiddle.net/3gf520ht/4/

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[1];
const item = wrapper.children[0];

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  if (wrapper.clientHeight < item.scrollHeight) {
    wrapper.classList.add("scrollbar-compensator");
  } else {
    wrapper.classList.remove("scrollbar-compensator");
  }
})
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
body { display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly; }
main { width: 40%; height: 80%; margin: 10vh 0; border: 1px solid; }
article { text-align: justify; }

main {
  padding: 0 2em;
  overflow: overlay;
}

main + main {
  overflow: auto;
}

.scrollbar-compensator {
  padding: 0 1em 0 2em;
}

article {
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pellentesque convallis vestibulum. Proin sed porta urna, eu fermentum velit. Nulla quis accumsan augue, mollis eleifend felis. Aenean venenatis faucibus erat, non ornare ex efficitur ut. Ut ligula urna, auctor non velit quis, ultricies aliquet diam. Nulla quis scelerisque nisl, rutrum consectetur diam. Etiam bibendum tellus orci, iaculis varius risus congue vitae. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum sed velit sit amet quam ultrices facilisis. Mauris malesuada vehicula purus, in blandit lectus pellentesque in. Duis luctus, risus et molestie venenatis, libero ligula volutpat augue, vitae bibendum arcu leo vel ligula. Etiam aliquet semper velit ut fringilla.</article>
</main>
<main>
  <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pellentesque convallis vestibulum. Proin sed porta urna, eu fermentum velit. Nulla quis accumsan augue, mollis eleifend felis. Aenean venenatis faucibus erat, non ornare ex efficitur ut. Ut ligula urna, auctor non velit quis, ultricies aliquet diam. Nulla quis scelerisque nisl, rutrum consectetur diam. Etiam bibendum tellus orci, iaculis varius risus congue vitae. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum sed velit sit amet quam ultrices facilisis. Mauris malesuada vehicula purus, in blandit lectus pellentesque in. Duis luctus, risus et molestie venenatis, libero ligula volutpat augue, vitae bibendum arcu leo vel ligula. Etiam aliquet semper velit ut fringilla.</article>
</main>
```

Comment: Ну со скриптом пусть остаётся в ответах - вдруг кому пригодится, но мне хотелось бы без. К тому же, в моём случае размер может меняться не только из-за изменения размеров окна. Ну и ещё у тебя баг в том, что не вызывается обработчик при загрузке страницы, т. е. начальное состояние получается некорректным. Ну и ширина скролла 17px, что обычно не равно 1em.